# MongoDB UPSERT in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have code that scans our multiple SANS and inserts each file into a mongoDB. The code also checks the database first and if the document exists it updates the document. These are huge file systems and the code does take ages to run so any effeciencies I can squeeze out would be great.

To find existing document and if not insert, is there a better way than:

```
if collection.find({'file_path': curpath}).count() > 0:       
    # update document  
elif collection.find({'file_path': curpath}).count() == 0:
    # insert document
```

Full code:

```
def scan_for_file(dir_path, storage_bucket):
    for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
        curpath = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
        if os.path.isfile(curpath):
            print('found file:', file)
            print('checking db for:', curpath)
            collection = db.file_collection
            if collection.find({'file_path': curpath}).count() > 0:
                print('found file in db', curpath)
                cursor = collection.find({'file_path': curpath})
                for document in cursor:
                    file_db_id = document['_id']
                    file_db_path = document['file_path']
                    file_accessed = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(file_db_path))
                    file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_db_path))
                    file_created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file_db_path))
                    file_size = os.stat(file_db_path).st_size
                    file_convert_size = convert_size(file_size)
                    utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                    update_id = collection.update_one(
                {'_id': file_db_id},
                {
                    "$set": {
                        "file_size": file_convert_size,
                        "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                        "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                        "file_created": file_created,
                        "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                        "file_modified": file_modified
                    },
                },
                upsert=True)
                    update_id
                    print('Updated ID:', file_db_id)

            elif collection.find({'file_path': curpath}).count() == 0:
                print('no file in db:', curpath)
                file_accessed = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(curpath))
                file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
                file_created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(curpath))
                file_size = os.stat(curpath).st_size
                file_convert_size = convert_size(file_size)
                utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                post = {"storage_bucket": storage_bucket,
                "dir_path": dir_path,
                "file_path": curpath,
                "file_name": file,
                "file_size": file_convert_size,
                "file_size_bytes": file_size,
                "process_datestamp": utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                "file_created": file_created,
                "file_accessed": file_accessed,
                "file_modified": file_modified}
                posts = db.file_collection
                post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
                post_id
                print('New posted ID:', post)
            else:
                print('error')
```

Comment: Isn't it the case that `elif collection.find({'file_path': curpath}).count() == 0:` could just be replaced by `else:`, since the count can never be negative, right?

Comment: thats true - I just used elif since I might wanted to add more conditions around the validation of the file